# Top users functionality of stackexchange loses time reference when going from a less to more specific time frame

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, reputation-leagues

**Steps to duplicate**

1. Navigate to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/11/week/cooking (shows current week)
2. Click `year` (shows Year 2010)
3. Click `week`

**Bug**: Now shows "Week of Dec 28, 2009" at the URL: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/11/week/cooking/2010-01-01

**Expected behavior**

Step 3 should return me to the week I was previously viewing, not to the first week of the previous time frame.

*This occurs for all time frame navigation but is demonstrated most effectively with the above steps.*

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been addressed. You are taken back to the *current* week now. This is *much* better.